# pom.xml & PowerShell execution - UnauthorizedAccess error

Tags: maven, powershell, jenkins, pom.xml

I am trying to run PowerShell scripts in a Maven build, but am seeing the below error.

```
[INFO] --- exec-maven-plugin:1.6.0:exec (import) @ test-build ---
D:\Jenkins\workspace\test-build\Build\file.ps1 : File 
D:\Jenkins\workspace\test-build\Build\file.ps1 cannot be loaded 
because running scripts is disabled on this system. For more information, see 
about_Execution_Policies at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.
At line:1 char:1
+ D:\Jenkins\workspace\test-build\Build\file.ps1
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], PSSecurityException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess
[ERROR] Command execution failed.
org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1)
```

I have seen responses to this issue, which suggest you add the argument

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Force
```

or

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
```

But I am not sure where to add this.
Would this be directly added to the .ps1 file?

```
Called by Maven in Compile Phase 
Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Force
```

or

```
<executions>
    <execution>
    ...
    <configuration>
        ...
        <executable>PowerShell.exe</executable>
        <arguments>
            <argument>XYZ\file.ps1</argument>
            <argument>-ExecutionPolicy Bypass</argument>
        </arguments>
    </configuration>
</execution>
```

Thanks in advance for any feedback and/help

Comment: in the `arguments` section, add a string `-ExecutionPolicy Bypass`

Comment: Hi, As I've done above? Is that correct

Comment: Have you tried?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately the same error (I've added it to the original question)

Comment: Seems setting the ExecutionPolicy directly on the Jenkins server resolved the issue.